# Angular: Decode a Encoded UNICODE string to print symbols

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to decode a "UNICODE" encoded string:

Using Angular, how can I decode my data which is a unicode string?

```
data = "PABTAGkAZwBuAGUAZABGAG8AcgBtAGEAdAB0AGUAZABEAGEAdABhAD4APABGAG8AcgBtAGEAdAB0AGUAZABEAGEAdABhACAAVgBlAHIAcwBpAG8AbgA9ACIAMgAuADAAIgA"
```

I tried using `atob()` and it's not working as expected, as it is decodes a base-64 encoded string.